# Find mean within fixed number of rows--beginning of range of rows depends on presence of non-NA value

Tags: r

I need to find, by group, the mean of the values within a fixed-size range of rows in a single column, with the beginning of the range defined by the first non-NA in the column. So, the length of the range doesn't vary by group, but where it starts can. Also, if the range of rows (window) does not include a minimum number of non-NAs, a NA is returned.

Here's a toy example with the original dataset and the desired resulting dataset, where the window length is 5, the minimum required number of non-NAs is 3, Score is the variable to be averaged, and Person is the grouping variable.

ETA: Code for creating the source data frame:

```
Person <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3)
Day <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)
Score <- c(4, 5, 2, 6, 8, 2, NA, NA, NA, 2, NA, 6, NA, 4, 7, NA, NA, 5, NA, 6, 8)
source.df <- data.frame(cbind(Person, Day, Score))
```

Source data:

```
   Person Day Score
1       1   1     4
2       1   2     5
3       1   3     2
4       1   4     6
5       1   5     8
6       1   6     2
7       1   7    NA
8       1   8    NA
9       2   1    NA
10      2   2     2
11      2   3    NA
12      2   4     6
13      2   5    NA
14      2   6     4
15      3   1     7
16      3   2    NA
17      3   3    NA
18      3   4     5
19      3   5    NA
20      3   6     6
21      3   7     8
```

ETA: Derivation of means from 5-row windows, each beginning with the person's first non-NA value on Score

For Person 1, the window begins at the 1st row (where the first non-NA for Score is encountered) and ends with the 5th row, yielding a mean of 5:
mean=(4+5+2+6+8)/5

For Person 2, the window begins at the 2nd row (rowname=10 in the dataset) and ends with the 6th row (rowname=14). The 3 non-NA values in this window yield a mean of 4:
mean=(2+6+4)/3

For Person 3, the window begins at the 1st row (rowname=15 in the dataset) and ends with the 5th row (rowname=19). As there are only 2 non-NAs in this window, no mean is computed for this person:
mean=NA

Desired result:

```
   Person Mean
1       1   5
2       2   4
3       3   NA
```

My intuition is that this is a matter of filtering rows by index within Person, with the initial index value defined by row with the first non-NA value for Score, and then computing means within the filtered range (conditioned on the minimum non-NA value), but I'm probably overlooking other potential approaches.

Any help you can provide would be appreciated!

Comment: I don't get how you came up with those means. Can you please show the calculation steps? Why does person 1 have a mean of 5?

Comment: Also, could you please make your data directly copy-paste'able?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the top description of the problem you mentioned that you needed the range to begin at the first NA within the selected column ("with the beginning of the range defined by the first NA in the column"). However, your desired output does not lineup with that logic because person one's range wouldn't begin until row 7 and end at 8, person two would begin at row 9 and the 5 row window would end at 13, and person 3 would begin at row 16 and the 5 row window would end at 20. Because of your three non-NA rule all three of these would return no mean. (I believe this may be what caused the confusion in the comments.)

Based on your desired output and the intuition comment at the bottom I believe you want the range to start on the first non-NA value.

I have recreated the sample data that you gave and written a quick for-loop that produces the desired output. The steps are broken out to more clearly show the logic you described and this is done in base functions. You could easily combine the steps, reduce the number of objects being created, and move some of this over to dplyr functions.

```
data <- data.frame(Person = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3),
                   Day = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4,5,6,7),
                   Score = c(4,5,2,6,8,2,NA,NA,NA,2,NA,6,NA,4,7,NA,NA,5,NA,6,8))

peeps <- unique(data$Person)
means <- data.frame(Person = peeps, Mean = NA)

win <- 5
notNA <- 3


for(i in peeps){
  temp <- data[data$Person == i,]
  firstNA <- which.min(is.na(temp$Score))
  temp2 <- temp[firstNA:(firstNA+win-1),]
  NonNA <- sum(!is.na(temp2$Score))

  if(NonNA >= notNA){
    means[means$Person == i, "Mean"] <- mean(temp2$Score, na.rm = TRUE)
  } else {
    means[means$Person == i, "Mean"] <- NA
  }

}
```

Once you run the loop the dataframe `means` will have the output you are looking for. You can set `win` as the desired number of rows, and `notNA` and the minimum required number of non-NA's. Let me know if I misunderstood the beginning of the range thing.

This does have the consequence of creating extra rows if a person does not have a range greater than the preset window. This has no affect on the output because of the `na.rm = TRUE` in the mean function. If you expand this loop you may consider adding an if statement that will only reduce the data to the size of the window if the data has more rows than the window. For example if person 4 has only three observations in their range it will not worry about the preset window because three is less than five, but if person 5 has 15 observations it will only take the first five in range.

Comment: Blargh! Yes, that should bit should have read "first non-NA." Apologies for the sloppiness.

And yes, your solution accomplishes exactly what I need. Thanks for persisting despite my error!